# Starting Hive gives me a SessioniveMetaStoreClietnt runtime exception

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive, derby

Just followed the tutorial on Tutorials point for installing Hive, I am running Ubuntu 15.04, with Hadoop 2.6.0 and attempting to install Hive 1.2.1 with Derby 10.11.1.1 The full error when executing:

```
hive
```

is

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to instantiate
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient at
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
```

Any Assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check hadoop daemons are running or not..

Comment: @StaceyMorgan yes they are all running when I use the JPS call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
May be it could be due to more than one metastore_db. 

1. Remove "metastore_db".It should be under $HIVE_HOME/bin/metastore_db.

   You can locate it using "locate metastore_db"

   $ rm metastore_db/*.lck

2. Then restart hadoop cluster and the run hive from hive shell again. 
   See if it works or not.
```

**Edit**

The JDBC DriverManager can't find any suitable Driver for the given connection URL. Either the JDBC driver isn't loaded at all before connecting the DB, or the connection URL is wrong. Check the derby.jar in ur hive/lib path. is it derbyclient.jar or derby.jar. Also check $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml file for matching driver/connection url path

Comment: there seem to be no results when trying to locate metastore_db redid the entire tutorial but still to no avail...

Comment: A JPS call yields the following
15211 Jps
14635 ResourceManager
12484 NameNode
14486 SecondaryNameNode
14300 DataNode
14774 NodeManager
A [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j94dky3z07ok1lh/output.txt?dl=0) to the full error file from start-dfs.sh, start-yarn.sh and the hive command

Comment: in the Hive/lib file it is a derby-10.10.2.0.jar
The following property is in the hive-site.xml <property><name> javax.jdo.option.connectionURL</name> <value> jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value> </property>
I am able to start the derby server manually on the system within the installed derby folder/bin/StartNetworkServer

is there anything else that could be the problem or something I could try to get this to work?

Comment: I hae just noticed there seems to be a problem with connecting to the Derby Database, it was default set to user: APP pass: mine however it was stating no test connection was available for this user. do you know how I can get the default username/password for derby? I found online it was derbyuser/derbyuser however to no avail